# How to initialize GPIOTE in NRF52?

Tags: c, gpio, nrf52

For some reason this simple configuration of NRF52 sdk 15.3.0 doesn't work. I was trying to edit my code from gpio to gpiote and I cannot initialize even the event to recognize that the button has been pressed.

The NRF52832 is Active-low as I understand and also from running some tests.

I made sure that both: #define GPIOTE_ENABLED 1 and #define NRFX_GPIOTE_ENABLED 1 are defined.

What might be wrong?

```
#include "nrfx_gpiote.h"
#include "app_error.h"
#include "nrf_log.h"
#include "nrf_log_ctrl.h"
#include "nrf_log_default_backends.h"

#define BUTTON_PIN_NUMBER 13

void button_event_handler(nrfx_gpiote_pin_t pin, nrf_gpiote_polarity_t action)
{
    NRF_LOG_INFO("Button event detected");
}

int main(void)
{
    NRF_LOG_INIT(NULL);
    NRF_LOG_DEFAULT_BACKENDS_INIT();

    nrfx_err_t err;

    // Initialize nrfx_gpiote
    err = nrfx_gpiote_init();
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err);

    // Set up button as GPIOTE input with pull-up resistor
    nrfx_gpiote_in_config_t btn_config = NRFX_GPIOTE_CONFIG_IN_SENSE_TOGGLE(false);
    btn_config.pull = NRF_GPIO_PIN_PULLUP;

    err = nrfx_gpiote_in_init(BUTTON_PIN_NUMBER, &btn_config, button_event_handler);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err);
    nrfx_gpiote_in_event_enable(BUTTON_PIN_NUMBER, true);

    while (true)
    {
        NRF_LOG_FLUSH();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app_gpiote.c file was missing inside the drivers.